# SELECT value AS (desc) not working in subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

[image: AS query not working]

As(no pun intended) you can see in this screenshot the AS statement is not changing the title of the returned query when the AS is located in the subquery.

The right side of the picture is my exp_tables table.  The goal here is to figure out what level the player is in each specific skill(so in my Java application I can put it in a nice progressbar).  Please let me know if there is something wrong with my SQL for the AS, or if you want to be really helpful, let me know if there is a better way I should be doing this.  Thanks so much for your help.  Love this site; hoping I can be smart enough to help others soon.

***EDIT***
Yes sorry for forgetting to upload the code >.<

```
SELECT 
skill_alchemy_exp, ((SELECT exp_tables.id AS alchemy_lvl FROM exp_tables WHERE skill_alchemy_exp < tradeskills LIMIT 1)-1), 
skill_axes_exp, ((SELECT exp_tables.id AS axes_lvl FROM exp_tables WHERE skill_axes_exp < weapons LIMIT 1)-1), 
skill_baking_exp,((SELECT exp_tables.id AS baking_lvl FROM exp_tables WHERE skill_baking_exp < tradeskills LIMIT 1)-1),
skill_blacksmithing_exp,((SELECT exp_tables.id AS blacksmithing_lvl FROM exp_tables WHERE skill_blacksmithing_exp < tradeskills LIMIT 1)-1),
                                        skill_blocking_exp, skill_blunts_exp, skill_bows_exp, skill_carpentry_exp, skill_cooking_exp, 
                                        skill_crossbows_exp, skill_daggers_exp, skill_dark_exp, skill_earth_exp, skill_fire_exp, 
                                        skill_foraging_exp, skill_harvesting_exp, skill_healing_exp, skill_hiding_exp, skill_holy_exp, 
                                        skill_looting_exp, skill_luck_exp, skill_lumberjacking_exp, skill_milling_exp, skill_mining_exp, 
                                        skill_planting_exp, skill_polearms_exp, skill_smelting_exp, skill_swords_exp, skill_wands_exp, 
                                        skill_wind_exp
                                         FROM kisnard.characters
                                         WHERE name='Proskier'
```

Comment: Can you please post the SQL code. It will be a lot easier to diagnose rather than having to go off of a picture

Comment: added in the code, sorry for that, got trigger happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "AS" operator on a column inside a sub-query doesn't give an entire sub-query a name.  If you look at the left hand part of the picture, you'll notice the column names of the sub-selects are the selects themselves because you didn't give those "columns" a name.

It's hard to tell exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, but you can do something like this... which might be what you want:

`SELECT a, b, (SELECT xyz FROM ...) AS c, d, e, ...`

That lets you give an alias to the sub-query.

Comment: PERFECT, should have thought of this... thanks so much!!!  Now can you tell me if this is a crazy way, or if it is inefficient or something?  I'm no DBA.

Comment: It is a lot of SQL - if you were to make it any better, I would assume that you'd want to define some views and/or some user defined functions to take care of your math (though, it's just a -1).  If you're "no DBA", leave what you have if it works and as you learn more, you can always revisit it later.